# Upload excel file to google drive in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, laravel-7, maatwebsite-excel

```
Storage::disk('google')->put('test.txt', 'Hello World');
```

And

```
Storage::disk('google')->put('test.json', json_encode(Inventory::all()));
```

above two types of file uploading to google drive by using  google-api-php-client and nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive packages is working well in my laravel application.

```
    $filename = 'inventory'.date('dmY').'.xlsx';
    Excel::store(new InventoriesExport, $filename);
    $path = storage_path($filename);
```

I have saved excel file with data from database in local (app/public/storage). 
can anyone help me to upload/ save this excel file to google drive?